# EAGLE schematic capture and board layout problems

Tags: eaglecad

I’m about to start the manual and then auto routing process of my schematic see the following link for my schematic but before doing this I’ve read quite a lot on different bits of advice on completing the schematic properly before embarking on any routing.

With regards to the routing I’ve read up on main aspects such as the selection of the routing grid in relation to the trace width, avoiding dimension errors and avoiding clearance errors.

Regarding my schematic I’ve got two components with each having a pin that I do not need to connect to anything at all. I’ve followed different pieces of advice and realized there is no “not connected” library in Eagle hence I created mine as per the following link. I then connect this custom symbol to my IC pin but no connection takes place and when I run my ERC check I come across the following errors in relation to both pins:

- “No SUPPLY for POWER pin U1 TAB”.
- “Unconnected INPUT pin IC1 ADJ”.

[image: Schematic]

*[Original image](https://5a600546-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/bgedsadata/BGE%20ZIGBEE%20RELAY%20BOARD%20-%205%20-%20HARDWARE%20%20-%20SCHEMATIC%20BEFORE%20MANUAL%20AND%20AUTO%20ROUTING.png?attachauth=ANoY7cpDA_yHs9DxXptO5UikNg3Dne8lbXwk3LhuJeYb5DaSWfBU9YsdZSu77-5FOORi_tfBE30Fs_yOb-Qzr7RD1l220Zi0IUokRhQIdsXCTKtkJ5yf_EOtwnRQOFOXLCKpAyc8SgRyXSjpc0PoZSAmMZhLdteoH9yM-5ofeTk24_xYo1WVHA0K_UsrisLK_LBKoN3Byzh_vNRKR1v1kk81T4SF0KHC6a1JLzkXr3IBdpcw_2NFEtf7aSoBVYmv0p7m5QyVBQZuYCi3AlpByawJywdY0dM-dnkeuBKXtlj2U5WXlUqjMdA=&attredirects=0)*

In addition to the above problem, can anyone see any other issues with my schematic? Apart from the values of specific components which I intentionally deleted can anyone see any problem on my schematic that I might have not anticipated? Any help is appreciated.

Now moving on to the board routing (which BTW I undertook before realizing the above mentioned problem), I’ve come learn a lot in the recent days about the following things to watch out for when laying out components and subsequently undertaking the routing:

- Selection of the routing grid (in relation to the trace width): I have a routing grid of10 mil and in the DRC sizes setting I have a minimum trace width of 10mil.
- Selection of the trace width whilst watching out for current carrying traces.
- Avoiding dimension errors.
- Avoiding clearance errors.

The following link illustrates the placement of my components before I undertake manual routing and after but if need be auto routing. Just to mention in the image below I have already used the ratsnest tool

[image: Board placement]

*[Original image](https://5a600546-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/bgedsadata/BGE%20ZIGBEE%20RELAY%20BOARD%20-%205%20-%20HARDWARE%20%20-%20BOARD%20LAYOUT%20BEFORE%20MANUAL%20AND%20AUTO%20ROUTING.png?attachauth=ANoY7co6TU6BBOUSfQ75ucRvqBHlylV5WIV47wtvt7dDNcbJJbxtTXVtYUbmub04sqKLn_WjlBdjHFyCl-tt2vL7oHP8HWXB9-fLTa4_w2Ti5cFkufvQeiaJ8-QWrFAVw2z-J7qMUGwynFu9N4WXByB7g_0RiKFwAmSXMz4pWekVSXezeIFIF0pZ3k2eR1S4cyj-fWBUzY5SM1jicwmMmwRW0ug4DLv4qcOqhr2WXmYgwjfkeRx_BjGmVXoaYtOiFkCQGGnAfrEyrFoM9ktWXbry2KO0sbYtOTk8OaVbhj3sE0s6LqlpQZZbKlWmQLvF_n4kkLTPbNAM&attredirects=0)*

Can anyone please identify anything at all that would cause me a problem in any way? Again any help is appreciated as it would save me time and effort solving errors.

Comment: Did you forget the ">VALUE?" text on some of your components? Also, changing the basepoint of ">NAME?" will move it to the standard spacing.

Comment: The positioning of R27, R43, R45, and R46 are suspect. Careful with the radiation pattern of U$2. P1 is going to be awkward if you ever want to sandwich the board between two others; I recommend moving it over near (but not *too* close to) S3.

Comment: You don't say what U1 and IC1 are, but as long as you know what you are doing, you can just Approve the ERC errors from Eagle and ignore them for now on.  BTW, you IC numbering is inconsistent, since you have format Ux, U$x, and ICx all on the same schematic.

Comment: In CAD systems I've used, ERC and DRC errors are just treated as warnings to the user, and do not prevent the program from creating the PCB  or board manufacturing files.  ERC and DRC errors can be ignored, as long as you are sure that they are acceptable for your design.  (It is best to minimize such errors if possible, of course.)

Comment: @Ignacio: For U$2 which is the ETRX357HR Telegesis zigbee module I’ll be using the following antennae. I’ve moved the suspect looking resistors (R27, R43, R45, and R46) inwards and I guess u mentioned this in order to avoid dimension problems. As for the standard spacing of the values and names I’ll correctly rename everything. I’ve also moved P1 which is my programming header.

Comment: @tcrosley: U1 is a LDO 3.3v voltage regulator – see http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22049e.pdf and IC1 is a LDO 5v voltage regulator – see http://fairchildsemi.com/ds/LM/LM7805.pdf. As for the standard spacing of the values and names I’ll correctly rename everything.

Comment: @Ignacio: Here's the antennae I mentioned https://sites.google.com/site/bgedsadata/BGE%20ZIGBEE%20RELAY%20BOARD%20-%205%20-%20HARDWARE%20%20-%20ANTENNAE.png?attredirects=0

Comment: To improve my design as per my 1st post I'll be making the following changes: Change 1: Using net classes I’ll change the size of the of all +5V and +3.3V carrying traces from 10mils to 24mils. I’ll manually route these traces. Change 2: Connect +5v to pin 1 of the DA-15 connector and GND to pin 8 of the DA-15 connector. This would supply power to the EasyDAQ card. On my breadboard setup I am supplying power to the EasyDAQ card using my breadboard setup hence on the PCB this shouldn’t be an issue. I’ll manually route these traces.

Comment: Continuing with the changes I'm making: Change 3: Change of LM335 temperature sensor device in schematic as custom sensor device created from LM35 (as LM335 and LM35 have the same footprint ) indicates the +5v pin as a GND pin as opposed to a +5V pin. See this link for download of the .bxl file which you will convert to the desired CAD format i.e. Eagle. | Change 4: Manually re-route majority of the traces to keep them on top layer whilst avoiding of right angle traces. This might mean fewer vias but what impact on the board (i.e. apart from making the manufacturing of the PCB cheaper)?

Comment: Continuing with the changes I'm making: Change 5: Connection of resistor directly between RX/pin 18 of zigbee module to Tx/pin 17 of PIC18F2580. | Change 6: Re-positioning of the temperature sensor based on the ground plane advice.

Answer (score 1):

U$1 has a TAB on that back that is probably a heatsink. Check to see if it is ground-connected, high-voltage, or floating. I'm assuming its your voltage regulator. Make a big polygon pour around this tab for heat sinking. From experience, these can heat up a lot. The warning EAGLE is telling you is that the IC symbol is listed as a power input and wants either a ground symbol or a power symbol to be connected to this pin. It appears to be floating in your schematic. If the TAB is internally connected to ground, then add a connection to the ground pin and the warning will go away.

Generally, its always a good idea to stick a wire on an IC pin, give it a name, and then connect it to a test pin that you can put on your board later for debugging. This can greatly help you down the road and also make your unconnected warnings go away.

Comment: For U1 which indeed is a LDO 3.3v voltage regulator – seeww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22049e.pdf in its datasheet i.e. as per diagrams on page 2 or page 11, I can’t seem to identify if the tab is internally connected to ground. For your information I’m using the SOT-223-3 package